# gsl_function alternative for c++

Tags: c++, c, c++11, gsl

I am switching from C to C++, and I would like to optimally use the additional features that become available and avoid things considered 'C-style' like `void *` pointers. Specifically, I am trying to make a `gsl_function`-like interface (NOT a wrapper to use gsl in C++).

In C, I wrote several routines for root-finding, integration ... that use a `gsl_function`-like interface to pass mathematical functions to these routines. This interface looks like this:

```
struct Function_struct
{
  double (* p_func) (double x, void * p_params);
  void * p_params;
};
typedef struct Function_struct Function;

#define FN_EVAL(p_F,x) (*((p_F)->p_func))(x,(p_F)->p_params)
```

and can be used in the following way:

```
struct FuncParams_struct { double a; double b; double c; };

double my_sqrt(double x, void * p) {
    struct FuncParams_struct * p_params = (struct FuncParams_struct *) p;
    double a = p_params->a;
    double b = p_params->b;
    double c = p_params->c;

    return a/sqrt(x+b)+c;
}

Function My_Sqrt;
My_Sqrt.p_func = &my_sqrt;
struct FuncParams_struct my_params = { 1.0, 1.0, 0.0 };
My_Sqrt.p_params = &my_params;

// Call the function at a certain x
double result_at_3 = FN_EVAL(&My_Sqrt, 3);

// Pass My_Sqrt to an integration routine 
// (which does not care about the parameters a,b,c 
// and which can take any other Function to integrate)
// It uses FN_EVAL to evaluate MySqrt at a certain x.
double integral = integrate(&My_Sqrt);

// Easily change some of the parameters
My_Sqrt.p_params->a=3.0;
```

As you can see, this allows me to create an instance of the `Function` structure, which contains a pointer to some function parameters (which are typically contained within another structure) and a pointer to a 'normal' C function. The great thing about this is that the routines that use `Function` only need to know that it is a function that takes a double and returns a double (they use the `FN_EVAL` macro). They do not have to care about the type and number of parameters. On the other hand, I can easily change the values stored in the parameters from outside of the routines.

I would now like to have the features highlighted above in a C++ Function. I searched a lot for what would be the best way to get this, but I could not find it (partly because I am a bit overwhelmed by the possibilities of C++ as compared to C). Thus far, I was thinking to make a `class Function`. This `class` could than store the actual function definition and it could be made callable by defining the `operator()`, such that again routines do not have to care about the parameters. The `operator()` could thus be used instead of the `FN_EVAL` macro.

The things that I could not yet decide/find are:

- how I would store the parameters. I was thinking about using a template typename. However, as far as I understand, then also the class itself needs to be a template, in which case also the routines should accept a templated class. I do not want to use a `void *`.
- how I would change the parameters that are stored in my `class Function`. Should I make them public such that I can easily change them, or should I keep them private and write some interface to access them? In the latter case, how should I go about this? Since I will be considering a large variety of parameters (both in number and in type).

Things to consider:

- I found a lot of questions and answers about wrappers to use gsl-routines within C++. That is not what I am looking for.
- I also looked at the STL `<functional>`. As far as I could figure out, it does not fulfill my requirements for the parameters that I can store within the Function. However, I can be wrong about this.
- My functions can be rather complex (i.e., not just one-line things like the example above) and the parameters can themselves contain a mixture of doubles, ints, structures...
- I would like to have the possibility to extend the `Function class` to higher dimensions, i.e. f(x,y,z). In C, I had for example

  ```
  struct FunctionThree_struct
  {
    double (* p_func) (double x, double y, double z, void * p_params);
    void * p_params;
  };
  typedef struct FunctionThree_struct FunctionThree;
  #define FN_THREE_EVAL(p_F,x,y,z) (*((p_F)->p_func))(x,y,z,(p_F)->p_params)
  ```
- I do care about efficient function calls. Especially for higher dimensional integrals, the functions will be called millions of times.

Comment: You should take a look at the `std::function` class template and the `std::bind` template function for binding known parameters and placeholders. :)

Comment: And of course learn about [lambdas](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) (which can often replace `std::bind`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ you can do all that using templates and [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function). For example:

```
// your header file
#include <functional>
namespace myNumerics {
    // version taking std::function argument, implemented in source
    double integrate(double a, double b, std::function<double(double)> const&func,
                     double err=1.e-9);

    // template version taking any callable object, including function pointers
    template<typename Func>
    inline double integrate(double a, double b, Func const&func, double err=1.e-9)
    {
        return integrate(a,b,std::function<double(double)>(func),err);
    }
}

// your source code, implements the numerics
double myNumerics::integrate(double a, double b, 
                             std::function<double(double)> const&func,
                             double err)
{
    some clever code here (but do not re-invent the wheel again);
}

// application code, uses the template version
void application(double a, double b, double c)
{
    // ...
    auto f = myNumerics::integrate(0., 1., [=](double x) { return a/sqrt(x+b)+c; });
    // ...
}
```

In particular, don't bother with `std::bind` (which is a C++ dinosaur from the dark ages before [lambda expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)). `std::function` is a very powerful method to encapsulate essentially anything that can be called, allowing you to implement the nitty-gritty details of your code in a well hidden source code, i.e. no need to expose the details in a template version (which necessarily must reside in a header file).

Note also that, unlike the situation with C, you can overload the function (here `integrate()`) to take different types of arguments. Here, I used a specific version taking `std::function` and a general templated version taking anything. It will compile as long as `std::function` can be initialized from whatever `func` object is passed (in case of an error, the compiler message may be rather cryptic, though).

This generality of `std::function` comes at the price of one indirection, creating a small overhead. Note, however, that this overhead is also present in your C implementation (via the `Function.p_func` pointer). Typically, that overhead is not critical, but in case it is, you can expose the implementation directly as a `template` in the header file. This avoids the overhead, but requires compilation of every instance (of the `integrate()` routine) you use.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. It seems like this implementation is very similar to the second solution of @ThomasRussell, except that you suggest to encapsulate everything in an ``std::function``, which avoids a compilation of every instance? The application code with the lambda expression will use the template version, I think?

Comment: @JorenV yes, that's right (I have added a corresponding remark to the answer).

Answer (score 4):

Your example in idiomatic C++11 using [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)/[`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) might look something like the following:

```
#include <functional>

double sqrt_fn(double x, double a, double b, double c);
double integrate(double x_0, double x_1, std::function<double(double)>);

void foo() {
    // Get parameters a, b, c
    double a = ..., b = ..., c = ...;
    double x_0 = ..., x_1 = ...;
    double integral = integrate(x_0, x_1, std::bind(&sqrt_fn, std::placeholders::_1, a, b, c));
}
```

This is quite general, but `std::function` internally uses type-erasure and so there is some overhead there. If there are performance requirements here, then you can consider using a lambda function and making `integrate` a template function that accepts a generic [`Callable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Callable). This would look something like:

```
double sqrt_fn(double x, double a, double b, double c);
template <typename Func>
double integrate(double x_0, double x_1, Func f);

void foo() {
    // Get parameters a, b, c
    double a = ..., b = ..., c = ...;
    double x_0 = ..., x_1 = ...;
    double integral = integrate(x_0, x_1, [a, b, c](double x) { return sqrt_fn(x, a, b, c) });
}
```

And is more transparent to the optimizer and involves no type-erasure.

Comment: This last solution looks nice! If I understand well, I can also put a, b and c in a structure and pass a reference to this structure? The function declaration would then be ``double sqrt_fn(double x, struct& mystructure)``. But how should I write the lambda then? ``[ ,&mystructure](double x){ return sqrt_fn(x, mystructure)}`` or ``[mystructure](double x){return sqrt_fn(x,mystructure)}``? Moreover, in the definition of integrate, can I evaluate the function just as ``f(3)``? As you might see, I have never used a lambda expression before...